# Foreign key constraint fails on nullable field

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, nullable, laravel-query-builder

I have a table `organizations`. This table has a primary `id` (int 10, unsigned, AUTO_INCREMENT).

In the table `organizations`, I also have a foreign key to the iself: `main_organization_id`. This has the following attributes: (int 10, unsigned, nullable, empty:TRUE, default:NULL).

Whenever I create a new organization:

```
  $organization = Organization::create($request->all());
```

Without a `main_organization_id` in my request, it fails with the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`myDB`.`organizations`, CONSTRAINT
>   `organizations_main_organization_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`main_organization_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`)) (SQL:
>   insert into `organizations` (`main_organization_id`) values
>   ())

But why does this fail? The field is nullable, does that mean I have to implicitly set `main_organization_id` to `null` in the request?

My `$fillable`:

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'main_organization_id',
    ];
```

My migration:

```
Schema::table('organizations', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->integer('main_organization_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('main_organization_id')->references('id')->on('organizations');
});**strong text**
```

**I want to prevent code like this: `$request['main_organization_id'] = null;` before creating my new row. Is this possible?**

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Can you check what is in your request ($request->all()) from the SQL error it seems that it's either empty or only single field is passed - main_organization_id

Comment: If you are send the main_organization_id field through a form you may create a "setter" method on your model to check for empty values and cast them as null

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should specify the field value while creating an Organization, you should do it like this:

```
$organization = Organization::create(array_merge([
    'main_organization_id' => null,
], request()->all()));
```

Hope this helps!